# How to calculate F_NODE and T_NODE fields in a street shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, network-analyst

I have developed a Streets shapefile from papermaps and using GoogleEarth. Can someone tell me a very simple method to bring values in F_NODE and T_NODE fields in my attribute table, so that I can ultimately develop Turn Tables and use my network for route optimisation?

Comment: I have made links/edges representing different streets in my Streets shapefile. I now want two fields in my attribute table - F_NODE and T_NODE which will show the starting nodes and end nodes of each of these links. What is the method to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a new question.  I recommend that you accept the Answer from @spatialfrog to this Question, and then Ask a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Esri's free ArcHydro Extension will do this [ArcHydro page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/hydro/01vn00000010000000.htm). Download from there or [Download](http://downloads.esri.com/blogs/hydro/AH2/ArcHydroTools_2_0.zip).

Once installed, load shapefile. From ArcHydro select Attribute Tools > Generate From/To Node for Lines.

This will generate FROM_Node & To_Node columns.

Comment: Dear Spatialfrog, you are an ArcGIS wizard....you really solved my problem. I downloaded ArcHydro v1.4 for my ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 and followed your advice and got the desired result.......THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @KoushikPaul that's great. Please upvote answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for some sort of Node Arc List (NAL) like ArcInfo Workstation coverages had.

Rather than look for this in shapefiles I would suggest trying to create a **[Turn Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Create_Turn_Feature_Class/004800000012000000/)** in a file geodatabase.

Comment: I have made links/edges representing different streets in my Streets shapefile. I now want two fields in my attribute table - F_NODE and T_NODE which will show the starting nodes and end nodes of each of these links. What is the method to do this?