# Asset point IDs, pipeline and flow direction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, network, flow, pipe-network

I have a data set of a sewage pipe network and point data (assets). I would like to:

- first calculate the flow direction of pipes (polyline feature)
- assign IDs to the pipelines using asset IDs (connecting). Eg, pipeline x starts from asset number 11 to asset number 10. I want to update the pipeline columns, one with downstream value of 10 (from asset) and another of upstream value of 11 (asset ID).

I have tried network analyst with ArcGIS but got stuck when trying to assign the IDs. Open to Python or any other code, or Modelbuilder.

[image: before assets and pipelines]

[image: after assets and pipelines with ID]

Comment: Hi @ChrisW calculating the flow direction using the tool was not a problem. I have created a Geometric network and it was also okay. The problem now is to assign both upstream and downstream values based on the flow direction.The logic is, line going from point A to B, I need to update the line fields with A value for upstream and B for downstream and keep going in a loop, updating all line attributes for up and down based on the points ID (direction, A to B, B to C etc). Thanks

Comment: Might take a look at this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73102/

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW, ArcHydro tool was not a complete solution but it was very helpful, I combined some of archydro tools + some python coding and it is working now. thanks again !

Comment: This post [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline?lq=1) is exactly what I was trying to achieve, Thanks @FelixIP